# How to read multiple column in a csv file in ipython

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I know the use of df['column name'] but what if i want to read multiple column names and show it in a dataframe? Thank You

Comment: `data_new = data[['column_1','column_2'...etc]]`

Answer (score 0):

```
data_frame = data[['column_1','column_2',..etc]]
```

you can add column names by just giving "column_name" column name should be exact as column name in csv